# MySQL not allowing the word "list" in textarea form post

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am writing a PHP form to submit data into MySQL database using textarea and has run into this strange problem: If I have the word "list" or "listed" or "listing" in the text, I will receive an error message saying "This site can't be reached" and "The connection was reset" with error message "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET."

I am using Goddady shared hosting with MySQL 5.6. Everything else seems to work fine. I've tried using bind_param and htmlspecialcharater but none worked.

The code is a simple SQL update:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" UPDATE content SET question_text = '$text' WHERE qid = '$qid' ");
$stmt->execute();
```

Is the word "list" forbidden as a security measure in certain shared hosting??

Comment: Try using prepared statements properly: `$stmt = $conn->prepare(" UPDATE content SET question_text = ? WHERE qid = ? "); $stmt->bind_param('ss', $text, $qid); $stmt->execute();`

Comment: The error you're getting is not because you're trying to store the word "list", "listed" or "listing". If the string is properly escaped, then there's no forbidden words. However, you should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that.

Comment: @Nick Indeed, however if their "qid" is an integer (value/type), the 2nd should be an "i". The question is missing a lot of detail.

Comment: The question is missing way too much code/detail, including what's being passed exactly from the input(s) and the db schema. This cannot be answered as posted.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick & Magnus Eriksson bind_param does not work...

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I used `s` because `$qid` is in quotes in OPs original query.

Comment: @tychen are you using `PDO`, not `mysqli`? Why does `bind_param` not work?

Comment: @Nick Their query may not be correct and it's anybody's ballgame. I've seen many times where they (OP's) used quotes around what are integers. I voted this one as being unclear. But if their "qid" column is a string, then what you posted in comments should have worked for them. They failed to update their post and respond to the missing details I mentioned. Another (good) point you made in another comment is asking which api they used to connect/query with; that one also is anybody's ballgame.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner as you say, it is indeed unclear (or off-topic for needing an MCVE).

Comment: Thanks @FunkFortyNiner for the tip. I am working on it.

Comment: Hi @FunkFortyNiner, I use PDO and tried the code below and it works for regular textarea update but still not taking in the word list.   
`$sql = " UPDATE content SET question_text = :text WHERE qid = :qid ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':qid', $qid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();`

Comment: @tychen You need to provide a lot more information to solve this. Show us your client-side code, and also more of your PHP code. Have you checked whether the update is actually happening even though you get an error?

Comment: @Nick, many thanks for the help. I was able to recreate the "problem" consistently and the code looks like this: PDO connection: `try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}`

Comment: The form: `<?php
include "../includes/db_conn.php";
$qid = 999;
$stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT question_text FROM content WHERE qid = $qid ");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
$text = $result['question_text'];
?>

<form method="post" action="./test_process.php">
    <input name="qid" value="<?php echo $qid ?>">
    <textarea autofocus required name="text"> <?php echo $text; ?> </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`

Comment: and the query: `<?php
include '../includes/headers.php';

$text = $_POST['text'];
$qid = $_POST['qid'];

try {
    $sql = " UPDATE content SET question_text = :text WHERE qid = :qid ";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':text', $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':qid', $qid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo $exception;
}`